# Finding an example satisfying $\mu(A)=3/4$, $\mu(B)=2/3$ and $\mu(A\cap B)$

Tags: measure-theory

I convinced myself that, if $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a probability space, $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$, $\mu(A)=3/4$ and $\mu(B)=2/3$, then $\mu(A\cap B)\geq 5/12$.

How do I find an example on a probability space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$, so that $\mu(A)=3/4$, $\mu(B)=2/3$, and $\mu(A\cap B)= 5/12$?

Comment: Try drawing a Venn diagram of two circles with points in (and outside) them: one circle containing $3/4$ of the points, one containing $2/3$ of the points, and with $5/12$ or more of the points in both circles.

Comment: If $\mu(A) = 3/4$, $\mu(B) = 2/3$, $\mu(A \cap B) = 5/12$, then it follows that $\mu(A \cup B) = 1$ which can certainly guide you in finding an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the space on 12 elements, where each element is equally likely to be sampled. A visual representation:  $A$ are the points marked with circles, $B$ are the points marked with crosses.
$$ \overset{1}O \overset{2}O\overset{3}O\overset{4}O\overset{5}\otimes\overset{6}\otimes\overset{7}\otimes\overset{8}\otimes\overset{9}\otimes\overset{10}\times\overset{11}\times\overset{12}\times  $$
(recall that $3/4 = 9/12 $ and $2/3 = 8/12$.)

Comment: Could you please explain what an "uniform measure" is? Did you mean discrete probability measure?

Comment: @UnknownW uniform mass placed at each point? Normalised counting measure? The law of the uniformly random variable on 12 points? You can also use Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and consider the intervals $A=[0,3/4], B=[4/12,1]$

Comment: Thank you. I apologize if I ask another one weird question, but is it allowed to let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure, as long as $X=[0,1]$ (or $[0,1)$?) so that $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a probability space?

Comment: @UnknownW Sure, you can use any interval, as long as you renormalise so that the total mass is 1.